# iFrame Embed Messes Up Page Layout & Causes Artifacts When Scrolling

Tags: jquery, iframe, embed, lazy-loading, vine

I have a page that's a grid of images using JQuery, JQueryUI, Masonry, Infinite Scroll & Lazy Load and some custom JS and CSS that all works great when the content is all images.

I recently tried to embed Vine and YouTube in there but anytime there's an iFrame embed, the page degrades when I scroll, my fixed header and footer jump around on scroll, the background disappears and massive artifacting happens.

I've tried removing the various js files and css to try to isolate the problem without any luck...any one have any ideas?

Here's the page without embed:
http://cryptic-anchorage-3726.heroku.com/test/test.html

Here's the page with embed which degrades:
http://cryptic-anchorage-3726.heroku.com/test/test2.html

Comment: Both pages look similar in my browsers (Opera + Chrome). I can't see any problems like the ones you describe. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm testing with Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43
and Safari Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) on OSX 10.8.2  I'll attach a screenshot of the degrading i see

Comment: Screenshot of degradation: http://cryptic-anchorage-3726.heroku.com/test/degredation.png

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after several days.  One of the parent containers (in this case the div with ID eventList)
had position: relative.  By removing it, everything renders normally!